# У виски может быть... лозунг?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

> Повернувшись к женщине, я неожиданно заплакала и спросила: "Как вы
>   думаете, что мне теперь делать?" И тут в беседу вступило хрупкое
>   создание в плаще до пят. Оно поправило капюшон, который под тяжестью
>   капель падал на лицо, и уверенно заявило: **"Keep going!"** Это было
>   настолько неожиданно, что я переспросила: "Как, вы говорите, теперь
>   жить?" Оно вытянулось во весь свой небольшой рост и твёрдо повторило
>   **знаменитый лозунг не очень хорошего виски**. Мамаша посмотрела на меня с сочувствием, а девочка застыла в требовательной позе.

Comment: Первому «неожиданно», которое более чем странно звучит (если оно не от лица, на тот момент себя не контролирующего), и из-за повтора, нужно найти замену. Чтобы не мучится, лучше удалить.

Comment: Спасибо, я прозевала дубль-неожиданно. )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть,  **“keep walking”?**

Это было настолько неожиданно, что я переспросила: "Как, вы говорите, теперь жить?" Оно вытянулось во весь свой небольшой рост и твёрдо повторило знаменитый **рекламный лозунг (девиз, призыв)** не очень хорошего виски.

https://m-kozhaev.ru/autootvetchik_131_istoriya_whisky_johnnie_walker/

Так появилась фраза “keep walking”. Переводить смысл можно по-разному – от буквального «продолжаем идти» до вариаций «держись бодрей», «твёрже шаг» и так далее.

Изменился и слоган. Прежний “keep walking” уступил место философскому девизу “joy will take you further” – «радость устремляет тебя вперёд».

Согласитесь, совсем иное звучание приобретает прежний **слоган виски** – “Keep walking!”

Слоган (чего? какой?) виски — родительный определительный падеж. Слоган можно считать рекламным лозунгом, тогда сочетание ***рекламный лозунг (слоган) виски*** воспринимается вполне корректно.

Comment: Шаронушка, спасибо! “Кeep walking” улетел к автору на осмысление. Как и вся сегодняшняя кучка вопросов с ответами.

Comment: Прилетело сегодня - в виде вёрстки. Молча и с “Кeep walking”.

Answer (score 3):

Это же художественное произведение. Вполне можно применить метонимию. Говорим же мы: "Съем ещё тарелочку", хотя едим суп в тарелочке, "Прочитал всего Пушкина", хотя читаем книги Пушкина. Почему нельзя "лозунг (слоган) виски", имея в виду слоган кампании по изготовлению виски?

По-моему, всё нормально, даже образно.

Answer (score 1):

Выбор слова (рекламный "лозунг"/"девиз"/"слоган" - заимствования одного и того же из разных языков) зависит от того, какая эпоха описывается. "Слоган" - вариант, устоявшийся за последние полтора-два десятилетия. Если важно передать дух более ранней эпохи, то лучше не подстраиваться под современные веяния. Но для всеобщего понимания я бы добавил слово "*рекламный*". Содержание же лозунга, как уже заметили, стоит уточнить.

Comment: Мне кажется. что слово "слоган" по стилю не подходит к этому тексту. Хотя оно всем понятно, но воспринимается  как как термин из газетной публицистики.  В нем мало художественности, даже фонетика какая-то резкая, неприятная для слуха.

Comment: Видимо, это потому, что "слоган" больше ассоциируется с печатной формой.